# Obfuscating method with throws clause

Tags: java, obfuscation, proguard

I'm using ProGuard to obfuscate my code.  My project is comprised of a few modules, each obfuscated independently.

One library includes an interface;

```
public interface IFace {
    public int methodA(boolean b) throws CustomException;
}
```

Another library provides an implmentation

```
public class IFaceImpl implements IFace {
    @Override
    public int methodA(boolean b) throws CustomException {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The library with the interface is built first, and the second is built against the obfuscated version.  Unfortunately the compile fails on the `@Override` as the interface does not have the throws clause.

I have proguard keeping the interface and all its members, but I can't figure out how to keep the throws clause.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I figured it out.

`-keepattributes Exceptions`

Comment: Thank You! This was a life-waster without your answer.

Comment: Huge time-saver.  Thanks.

Comment: Best answer. Saved the day @Cogsy!

Answer (score 0):

Example with Maven:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
    <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.6</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
            <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>proguard</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <proguardVersion>4.10</proguardVersion>
        <options>
            <option>-keepattributes Exceptions</option>
            <option>-keep public class some.package.SomeClass{*;}</option>
        </options>
        <libs>
            <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
            <lib>${java.home}/lib/jce.jar</lib>
            <lib>${java.home}/lib/jsse.jar</lib>
        </libs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```