# Proguard processing interface will delete the interface method throws

Tags: java, android, proguard, android-proguard

When I use proguard on Android, I found proguard after dealing with interface, the interface method of throws was deleted.

before:

```
public interface Factory {

Card create(Profile profile) throws CardException;

}
```

proguard-rules.pro:

```
-keep interface Factory { *; }
```

after:

```
public interface Factory {
Card create(Profile var1);
}
```

You can see that the throws of the method are removed.

I do not know the reason for optimize, obfuscator or shrink the reason.

Comment: if CardException is your custom class so you have to declare it also in proguard.

Comment: Yes， I did.      -keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115515/obfuscating-method-with-throws-clause -keepattributes Exceptions

Answer (score 0):

> replace `com.example` with base package of `CardException` Class and
>   put this line in proguard file

```
-keep class com.example.** { *; }
```